# Server Error: DropDownList not allowed multiple selections

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two DropDownLists and I'm adding Items like this:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    ddUserTarget.Items.Add(new ListItem(" ", "empty534534545"));
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        ddUsersSource.Items.Add(new ListItem(reader[1].ToString(), reader[0].ToString()));
        ddUserTarget.Items.Add(new ListItem(reader[1].ToString(), reader[0].ToString()));
    }
}
```

When I'm use one of this DropDownList after a button click or a autopostback there are this HttpException:

> In the DropDownList it's not allowed to select more than one item.
>   (0x80004005)

If I delete this line, the error will not appear:

```
ddUserTarget.Items.Add(new ListItem(" ","empty534534545"));
```

The error is triggered at this position:

> else if (ddUserTarget.SelectedValue == "test")

I really dont know what to do now....

Comment: Somewhere you are setting the selected item twice. This usually happens when you set the selected property via the `Items` collection.

Comment: There is no line of code where I set selectedindex or something.

Comment: Can you post more of the code that deals with `ddUserTarget`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are setting a value to "SelectedItem" in more than one place.
I suggest you clear the selected items before post back (at the page end).
for example:

```
DropDownList myDDL = new DropDownList();
myDDL.ClearSelection();
```

Comment: I tried to do it in Page_Load with if(!Page.IsPostBack)myDDL.ClearSelection();

But it did not help

Comment: Can you please post the entire class so I can further investigate?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it. On every postback I refilled the dropdownlist in the Page_Load. Like if(!Page.IsPostBack)fillDD();

Now it works. May you mean it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In while loop you are inserting same Items twice.

```
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            ddUserTarget.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("empty534534545"));
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ddUsersSource.Items.Insert(ddUsersSource.Items.Count,new ListItem(reader[1].ToString(), reader[0].ToString()));                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it did not help.

Comment: What is your dropdownlist name ?

Comment: I got two dropdownlists: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddUserTarget" runat="server">

<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" ID="ddUsersSource" runat="server">